# Next js useState does not work when I click on the button, event handling

Tags: next.js, frontend, event-handling

I am trying to add a menu button in my nav bar

the problem is that when I try to click on the image nothing happens

here is my menu bar code

```
"use client"
import { useState } from "react";
import MenuImg from "../../public/menu.png";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Menu() {
  const [menuOpen,setMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <Image
        onClick={()=>setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)}
        src={MenuImg}
        alt="menu image"
        className="md:hidden lg:hidden hover:scale-105 transition duration-300 ease-in-out cursor-pointer z-50"
      ></Image>
      <div
        className={
          menuOpen
            ? "fixed md:hidden lg:hidden left-0 top-0 w-[60%] h-full border-r border-r-gray-900 bg-pink-75 ease-in-out duration-500"
            : "ease-in-out w-[60%] duration-500 fixed top-0 bottom-0 left-[-100%]"
        }
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have researched the problem online and I did not seem to find any related issues, I have already deleted and restarted .next , I have tried it with different versions of next none of these worked

Comment: update your node.js version

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem

the issue was in the layout file I had it configured like this

```
  return (
<div>
  <Header />
  <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
  <Footer />
</div>
```

where it should have been configured in this way

```
return (
<html>
  <body className={inter.className}>
    <Header />
    {children}
    <Footer />
  </body>
</html>
```